# HP 2133 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screen

Im trying to install on this small pc. I created a USB with Rufus and good to go.
When im running the installation i can't see the whole screen Next buttons etc.
What to do?

I could install ubuntu 10.04 without any problems(cant install anything tho :( ), the screen adjusted automatically, but it's a bit outdated so i would rather 12.04.

Comment: 10.04 is out of support for a long time now, the software repositories are unavailable, reason why you can't install software. 12.04 will be out of support in a few months therefore there's no point in installing it either. Consider 14.04, 16.04 or 16.10.

Comment: Damn 14.04 was laggy on that pc. :(

Comment: 16.04 (LTS) or 16.10 do not necessarily need more resources than 14.04 and may provide better support for your VIA Chrome9 (unlikely but possible). That crap graphics is your main problem with Linux in that machine. Surprisingly, Windows 10 may work fine. Any Linux distro, OTOH, will struggle with hardware that never had good support and never will.